# WPF - Navigate to different pages inside a frame which is contained in Window?

Tags: wpf, navigation, window, frame

I have a Main window which contains a frame. Purpose is to display different views (pages) inside a frame.

```
<Window>
  <Frame Source="Page1.xaml" />
</Window>
```

Page1.xaml is of type **Page** and contains a button, say Button1. On click of Button1 I would like to navigate to Page2.xaml. However the following breaks the application at run time:

```
private void OnButton1Click(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   NavigationService.Content = null; //I tried this thinking exception is caused because Page1.xaml is already present in frame. But no luck! :(
   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

it throws **XamlParseException 'Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' threw an exception.'** Inner Exception reads ***Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.***

I suspect this has got something to do with style resources too because if I keep a blank grid in Page2.xaml navigation works without problems. :-|

***Edit***: Started adding elements with Styles one by one to Page2.xaml and realised that it breaks only when I add a style resource that sets embedded image (image comes from separate dll, Assets) as button content. Style in question is defined as below in a separate Style.xaml file (resource dictionary):

```
<Style x:Key="BackButton" TargetType="Button">
   <Setter Property="Content">
      <Setter.Value>
         <Image Source="/Assets;component/Images/back.png" />
      <Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

If I comment the Setter for Content property, navigation works fine. So as a quick solution I added back image as direct content of button on Page2.xaml.

Comment: What resources are you declaring/referencing in the `Style` that fails?

Answer (score 0):

This is from working code
But it does not use NavigationService
It updates the frame directly

```
PageDocFieldDetail pageDocFieldDetail = new PageDocFieldDetail();
framePageDocFieldDetail.Content = pageDocFieldDetail;
```